# how to get query string parameter to use in another function in another file via fetch?

Tags: javascript, netlify

I have a function on my client side that I am running that goes and fetches a netlify function with API info and returns the JSON data. I am trying to pass a query string parameter so that I can add it to the API url in the netlify function. How should I access the query string parameter in the netlify function?

Here is the function that fetches the netlify function.

```
  function  fetchNetlifyFunction() {


  let netFunction='http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/token-hider? 
  stateName=' + stateName;
     console.log(netFunction);
     fetch(netFunction);  

    }
```

And here is the netlify function

```
var alertEndpoint = "";
var parkEndpoint = "";



 exports.handler = function getURLS(event, context, callback) {

   // Get env var values defined in our Netlify site UI
   const {api_key, alert_api_url, park_api_url} = process.env;

    alertEndpoint = `${alert_api_url}${api_key}`;
    parkEndpoint = `${park_api_url}${api_key}`;



   };
```

I need to add the stateName Query string parameter to the alert endpoint and park endpoint urls, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab that from the previous fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which is part of the APIs provided by modern browsers to JS.

Try the following:

```
var url = new URL(netFunction);
var stateName = url.searchParams.get("stateName");
```